# How can I prevent navigation from top-level dropdown anchors?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a basic bootstrap v3 dropdown for the main navigation menu.  My code looks something like this:

```html
    <li>
      <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Level 1</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="somelink">Level 2</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Of course, `Level 1` doesn't have a destination, it just toggles the dropdown.  When you select `Level 2`, you reach a web page that dynamically generates what we call a `JobId` and then immediately re-directs you to the final destination, with the `JobId` as a query string in the URL.

Here's my issue: 
If a user would right-click on `Level 2` and choose "open in new tab" then all is well because they go through the `JobId` procedure first, and they end up with a new `JobId`.  However, if they accidentally right-click on `Level 1` and choose "open in new tab" then they get an identical copy of the page they are currently on, and therefore end up with 2 browser tabs with the SAME `JobId` which is a disaster for our application.

What I've tried:
I have tried having the top-level `href` attribute as `#`, tried it as a blank, tried omitting `href` completely, and I also tried giving it the URL to our "welcome" screen for just in case.

The only thing that has "kind of" worked was linking the top-level menu item to the welcome screen, however it has a side effect.  The very first time you load the page, the dropdowns work perfectly.  But once you choose a menu item once, then the very next time you click on a top-level item, instead of revealing the dropdown you are taken to the welcome screen.

Any other ideas on how I can prevent the `Level 1` items from doing anything other than revealing the dropdown menus?

Comment: Why are you using an anchor element? That's semantically wrong and doesn't match [the markup Bootstrap suggests](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#dropdowns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does Level 1 need to be an anchor? Just because that's how Bootstrap has it laid out, it doesn't have to be that. In fact, since that Level 1 anchor is already inside of a list item, just remove the anchor and place your 'Level 1' text inside of the list item.

Comment: It should be a semantically correct element, such as a button (which is [what Bootstrap suggests](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#dropdowns)). It can be styled to suit.

Comment: Actually you're correct, there should be some element there to trigger the open.On the other hand, the trigger can be removed entirely and just use a hover to open/close the menu.

Comment: That's also a bad approach since mobile doesn't have hover.

Comment: I use this same approach on a CMS I maintain...hiding anything from mobile is a bad approach as-is. So i display all nav items once you open the hamburger menu.

Comment: Thanks, I converted the top-level items to a `div` and styled them to look like the anchor tags looked!